# Scope of private variables

Tags: c++

We just started talking about classes in my intro to CS class and I am a bit lost on how to know when a variable is private or not. We had a lab today and this is what the .h file contained: 
(the class containing the below code is called personType)

```
class PersonType {
public:
    void print() const;
       //Function to output the first name and last name
       //in the form firstName lastName.

    void setName(string first, string middle, string last);
      //Function to set firstName and lastName according 
      //to the parameters.
      //Postcondition: firstName = first; lastName = last

    string getMiddleName() const;
    //function to return the middle name
    //Postcondition: the value of middlename is returned. 

    string getFirstName() const;
      //Function to return the first name.
      //Postcondition: The value of firstName is returned.

    string getLastName() const;
      //Function to return the last name.
      //Postcondition: The value of lastName is returned.

    personType(string first = "", string middle = "", string last = "");
      //Constructor
      //Sets firstName and lastName according to the parameters.
      //The default values of the parameters are null strings.
      //Postcondition: firstName = first; lastName = last  

private:
    string firstName; //variable to store the first name
    string middleName; //variable to store middle name
    string lastName;  //variable to store the last name
};
```

In int main, I declared an instance of the class called personType myself;

would the object myself have access to these private variables because it is apart of the same class containing the private variables? In what scenario would I not be able to access these private variables?

Comment: You won’t be able to access private members outside of this class (e.g. from the main function)

Comment: An object, by definition, has access to its own private members.   Unrelated functions, unless declared as a `friend`, do not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A member that is `private` can be accessed (without any or on any instance of the class) from within code written inside the class definition and all out-of-class definitions for members of the class.

That means in particular that where ever you implement `PersonType`'s methods, they can access the private members in their body.

Any other code cannot access the `private` members by default (without a `friend` declaration).

In particular if you create an object `PersonType person;` in `main` you cannot use `person.firstName`. You can do the same in the implementation of `PersonType::setName` though and you also can use the implicit instance's `firstName` in `PersonType::setName`'s implementation.

Accessibility is not specific to certain instances of classes. It is only a matter of the context in the code that the member names are used in. It doesn't matter whether the member is referred to as `firstName`, `person.firstName`, `this->firstName`, or any other way. In a member function, it also doesn't matter whether `person` is the current instance or some other instance of the class.

Each time the compiler encounters a name in your code it figures out to what declaration this name refers to. The accessibility check then looks at the context in which the name appeared and compares that to the result of the name-lookup to figure out whether the access should be allowed according to the rules above.

Answer (score 4):

any method that belongs to `PersonType` will have access to the private variables, for instance `string PersonType::getLastName() const`

any other code, including main(), will not be able to access these variable.

```cpp
void main() 
{
  PersonType myself;
  myself.getLastName(); // OK!
  std::cout << myself.lastName; // ERROR! lastName is private
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, to know if it's private or not, you just have to check if it's in a `private` section of the class declaration :-)

But, expanding on that, an object (like `myself`) will *always* have access to its private members (and private members of *other* objects of that class, assuming it can see the actual object itself). Privates are generally<sup>(a)</sup> meant to prevent things *outside* the class from accessing them directly.

This prevention includes, for example, trying to do things like `myself.firstName = "Pax"` from your `main` function.

The usual way to get that level of access from outside is to provide getters and/or setters in the class. Using these allows you to do things like:

- catch invalid attempts to change the variables; or
- hide the internals of the class so that they can be changed without affecting the interface.

That is what those `get*` and `set*` methods in the code you posted are for, although I would have personally returned constant references for the getters - there's little point in copying something that may only be read:

```
const string &PersonType::getFirstName() const { return firstName; }

const string &name = pt.getFirstName(); // to just use it as is.
string name = pt.getFirstName(); // to get a modifiable copy.
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Things tagged as `friend` can bypass this protection but I won't cover that here, it would unnecessarily complicate the answer. You may also want to look into `protected` at some point, this allows sub-classes to access members (private members are off-limits to sub-classes) while still protecting them from things outside the inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of `personType` has access to its own copies of the private variables of the class. It also has access to the private variables of other instances of the same type.

Non-`personType` variables and functions will not be able to see those variables. That includes variables of the type of any class you might derive from `personType`.

Comment: @uneven_mark Quite true. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

> would the object myself have access to these private variables because it is apart of the same class containing the private variables?

This comes from a perspective that sees objects as having access to things. For some meanings of "access", this perspective can be useful. However, when the meaning of "access" involves access specifiers (`public`, `protected`, and `private`), it is more useful to view **code** as having access, rather than **objects**.

Code implementing a class has access to the `private` details of that class. Other code does not. In particular, the code in your `main` function has no access to any private details of any class.

*(The `friend` keyword can change things, but it should not. If something declared a `friend` cannot reasonably be considered part of the implementation, then it likely has no business being a `friend`.)*

Answer (score 0):

> would the object myself have access to these private variables because it is apart of the same class containing the private variables?

Yes. Each instance gets its own copy of the variables (unless you declare them `static`, but that's probably a topic for another time). So, if you have an object:

```
PersonType person;
```

There is conceivably these variables:

```
person.firstName
person.middleName
person.lastName
```

And, just to cover all my bases, these are available **inside** the class. So take the following function:

```
string getMiddleName() const;
```

The implementation of this function **will** have access to all private variables. So, for instance:

```
string PersonType::getMiddleName() const {
    return middleName; // if this is called from person (that is, person.getMiddleName())
                       // then "middleName" here is person.middleName
}
```

Here, `person.getMiddleName()` can access `person.middleName`.

> In what scenario would I not be able to access these private variables?

Most every other scenario where a function is not a part of the class `PersonType`. However, I will give some examples for the sake of clarity.

```
int main() {
    PersonType person;

    // bad
    person.middleName;

    return 0;
}
```

Here, you can't access `person.middleName` because `main()` isn't a part of `PersonType`. It is `main()`, i. e. another function. A general rule of thumb is if it is not part of the class, you can't access private variable.

```
void function(PersonType person) {
    person.middleName; // still can't do it
}
```

Here, `function()` is not part of `PersonType`, so it doesn't have access to `middleName`.

There is only one exception to this rule about not being able to access private variables outside the class, and that is [`friend` functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend). To create a `friend` function, you have to modify your header a bit:

```
class PersonType {
public:
    friend void friendFunction(PersonType person);

    //...
};
```

Now, `friendFunction()` can access private data members:

```
void friendFunction(PersonType person) {
    person.middleName; // it's fine. We're friends
}
```

The most common use of friend functions is with a slightly advanced topic called ["operator overloading"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-c/), which your class will almost certainly go over eventually.

---

Anyway, in the mean time, think of it this way: Is it part of the class? It can access private members. Is it a friend of the class? It can also access private members. Is it anybody else? No, it can't access private data members.